# Need advice for linking with shared library

Tags: 12.04, monodevelop

i am working with Awesomium SDK for linux 32 bit system, i have followed these instructions to manually install Awesomium on any Linux distro, you'll need to add the 
shared library to your system's library search path. On Ubuntu, 
you can use the following commands:

```
cd awesomium_v1.6.5_sdk_linux32
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/awesomium-1.6.5
sudo cp -r build/bin/release/* /usr/lib/awesomium-1.6.5
```

If the folder /etc/ld.so.conf.d does not exist:
    sudo mkdir /etc/ld.so.conf.d

And finally:
    sudo cp config/awesomium-1.6.5.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d
    sudo ldconfig
Till here i followed all steps.Then there is a step that i am not able to understand,so i have not done this below step :

To link against Awesomium, you should use "-lawesomium-1.6.5", for example:

```
g++ main.cpp -lawesomium-1.6.5 -o MyApp
```

And finally i followed this final step, to work with the Awesomium.Mono Samples, copy the Awesomium.NET folder
to a writeable location and open: Samples/Mono/Awesomium.Mono Samples.sln
in MonoDevelop.

I copied the folder in desktop and opened it from there.
NOw after following these steps when i run my project it gives me exception that System.dllnotfoundexception libawesomium-1.6.5.so.0
I need help to solve this exception, when i manually check it this .so lib is available in /usr/lib/awesomium-1.6.5, but somehow its giving me this bug. So please help me out on this. As far as softwares are concerned i have installed monodevelop, xsp4 server, libx11-dev.

Regards
Rohit

Comment: any help plz...

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Wheezy 32bit you need to install `libjpeg62`:

```
apt-get install libjpeg62
```

This will fix the problem!